# /var/run/php-fpm.www-data.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, php-fpm

На моем сервере (Debian 8) стоит nginx + apache.
Когда я работаю в панели phpMyAdmin, в логах сайта нахожу такое:

```
[crit] 12212#0: *216305 connect() to unix:/var/run/php-fpm.www-data.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 123.123.123.25, server: site.com, request: "GET /phpmyadmin/db_structure.php?server=1&db=users&token=3b0dbdca858219ccd7a85cb3f61911b9&ajax_request=true&ajax_page_request=true&menuHashes=6e077c32&_nocache=1464879170462427468 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.www-data.sock:", host: "site.com", referrer:http://site.com/phpmyadmin/index.php?db=...
```

Такие ошибки появляются только от phpMyAdmin. Странность в том, что на моем сервере нет и не было никогда php-fpm. Я конечно же пробовал его установить, но ошибка не исчезла. Я его удалил из-за отсутствия необходимости в нем. Также замечаю, что phpMyAdmin работает медленнее чем на старом сервере где не было nginx. Выходит, что данная проблема тормозит скорость работы панели. Обычный запрос типа

```
SELECT * FROM `bookmarks` WHERE `id` = 1
```

в панели выполняется намного дольше чем запрос через php

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `bookmarks` WHERE `id` = 1");
```

Не знаю какие конфиги/логи еще нужны, выкладываю пока конфиг от nginx

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  2048;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

  proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
  proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
  proxy_send_timeout 600s;
  proxy_read_timeout 600s;
  client_body_timeout 6m;
  client_header_timeout 6m;
  send_timeout 6m;
  proxy_buffers 16 32k;
  proxy_buffer_size 32k;
  client_max_body_size 100m;
  large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;
  proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;

gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_min_length 10;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/x-ic$
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_disable msie6;


    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts/*/*;

server {
        server_name localhost;
        disable_symlinks if_not_owner;
        listen 80;
        include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
        large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;

location @fallback {
                error_log /dev/null crit;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                access_log off;
                proxy_buffer_size 32k;
                client_max_body_size 32M;
                client_body_buffer_size 512k;
                proxy_connect_timeout 90;
                proxy_send_timeout 180s;
                proxy_read_timeout 180s;
}
}
}
```

Comment: посмотрите конфиги phpmyadmin: config.inc.php, $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'], mysql my.cnf  секция [client], PHP: php.ini [MySQL] mysql.default_socket

Comment: судя по формату, это логи nginx, который пытается использовать сокет php-fpm и не находит его. найдите в конфигурации этот адрес, чтобы разобраться

Comment: а что выдаёт команда `grep -rl php-fpm /etc/nginx`?

Answer (score 1):

Переустановил php-fpm

В `/etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/phpmyadmin-nginx.conf`

Исправил путь `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.www-data.sock;`
на

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
```

т.к php-fpm создает php5-fpm.sock

В `afterlogic-nginx.conf` (тот же каталог) тоже стоит неверный путь к сокету. Исправил.